# Adding rows to a matrix matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vectorization

I asked a question earlier regarding a function I'm trying to plot. I wasn't able to get a solution that worked so I'm trying to look at it a different way.

I have  a function A which returns to me a 3x1 matrix for an input t and d.

I want to make a 3xn matrix K which has all the possible answers for function A for inputs t and d, in the form `0:1:360` and `0:0.05:0.75` respectively.

So in other words I want to add a new row to the matrix K from the function A which is calculated from the values of t and d.

So for two solutions of A, it would be:

`K=[1,2,3;3,4,5]` or something along those lines.

How can I make a matrix K like that?

EDIT: Included the function

```
function [ X ] = type1b(t,d)
%UNTITLED2 Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here

%Definition of variables (most will be variable)
qr1=[0,0,1]; %Axis of rotation of link 1 (v)
qr2=[0,0,1]; %Axis of rotation of link 2 (v)
H1=[1,0,0]; % Link 1 (v?)
H2=[1,0,0]; % Link 2 (v?)
U1=[cos(t/2),sin(t/2)*qr1]; %quaternion rotor for link 1
U2=[cos(t/2),sin(t/2)*qr2]; %quaternion rotor for link 2
Ug=U1; %Globalising Quaternion (v)


H2g=quatrotate(Ug,H2); %Globalised H2
X=quatrotate(U1,H1)+ quatrotate(U2,H2g)+d;
```

Comment: without having the form of your function it is not clear why you can't just enter 2 vectors, `d` and `t` to get that answer. Please add your function to the question.

Comment: Just added the function :)

Comment: see the solution in my answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To vectorize your function, Just edit the last line of your function to:

```
X=quatrotate(U1,H1)+ quatrotate(U2,H2g)+repmat(d,[1 3]);
```

and then you can use

```
[t d] = ndgrid( 0:360, 0:0.05:0.75);
type1b(t(:),d(:))
```

Comment: You're like a God :p Thank you very much! Out of curiosity are there any online courses that I can take to quickly get myself up to speed in MATLAB?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming function `f` cannot be vectorized, you can use nested loop:

```
all_t = 0:1:360;
all_d = 0:.05:.75;
K = zeros( numel(all_t)*numel(all_d), 3 ); % pre allocate - very important
ii = 1;
for t = all_t
    for d = all_d
        K(ii,:) = f( t, d ); % one line
        ii = ii+1;
    end
end
```

On the other hand, if `f` can be vectorized, that is accepting several pairs of `t` and `d` and returning the corresponding multiple rows of `K` then this should be more efficient:

```
[t d] = ndgrid( all_t, all_d );
K = f( t(:), d(:) );
```

Comment: I just added my function to the original question. I'm trying to work your solution into it